# Ionic 4 Tabs panel not showing on all pages

Tags: ionic4

I'm developing an app using Ionic 4 and there is a Tab Panel in the bottom of the page. the thing is that tab panel is not showing on all other pages. how to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to with the routing.

Say you put your tab panel in a page called `tabs`. All those other pages that you want to have that same tab panel, have to be declared as children to your `tabs` page.

So your `tabs.module.ts` should look like something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'child1'
            },
            {
                path: 'child1',
                loadChildren: './child1/child1.module#Child1PageModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'child2',
                loadChildren: './child2/child2.module#Child2PageModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'child3',
                loadChildren: './child3/child3.module#Child3PageModule'
            },
        ]
    },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]});
```

Then you can link your child pages in the `ion-tab` as follows:

```
  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button tab="child1">
        <ion-label>My child 1</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="child2">
          <ion-label>My child 2</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="child3">
        <ion-label>My child 3</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
```

Note how what is set for `tab` attribute in each `ion-tab-button` agrees with the a `path` in the routes.

Comment: Ya, that's correct. but let's say if i have another page called profile. when i navigate to that page using <ion-button routerLink="/profile">, the tab panes disappear.

Comment: @tharinducs7 that's the intended behavior. The tab is only available to the page it is defined in and its child pages. Each and every page in which you want to have that tab panel, has to be a child of your tabs page.

Comment: ah okay! Thank You :)